# Keyboard no longer works on Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100

Tags: laptop, keyboard, toshiba-laptop

On my Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100, the keyboard is not working. No matter what I press nothing responds. The touch screen is still working, and everything seems to be working properly, but I have zero keyboard function! Any suggestions? I was up a few nights ago using my laptop and everything worked fine, the next morning when I woke up I opened it and turned it back on from sleep mode and none of my keys, nor mouse worked. Really strange to me, I did not add anything to my laptop or do anything, just simply used it one night woke up the next morning and can not use my key board for the last 3 days now.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As is, this request is pretty broad and hard to answer without just taking a shot in the dark. Could you provide any details that could help someone diagnose your problem? Have you made any recent changes to your laptop -- installed new software, fiddled with hardware, spilled something on it, etc? Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/920851/edit) your question to include these details.

Comment: Did you try rebooting the laptop?

Comment: what is the OS?

Comment: http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Keyboards-Touchpads/Laptop-keyboard-and-touchpad-not-working-in-Windows-8-1/td-p/490809/page/5 READ word by word. (Poster Jerry_Lippey)

Comment: Is there an illuminated Caps Lock indicator that is part of the keyboard? Does it function?

Answer (score 1):

Pull off the back cover and reset the bios using the small metal button next to the bios battery.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Francisco Tapia for the helpful link! As well as the user on the [Toshiba Forum](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Keyboards-Touchpads/Laptop-keyboard-and-touchpad-not-working-in-Windows-8-1/td-p/490809/page/5) "colsearle"

I had this same issue with a student laptop. Here is the resolution:

1. Access the registry (Run > Regedit)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`
3. Edit the value *UpperFilters* to read `kbdclass`
4. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`
5. Edit the value *UpperFilters* to read `mouclass`
6. Reboot

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) should also include an explanation as to *why/how* it answers the OPs question.  Also, it appears you're citing a source, in which case providing a link would be appropriate.