# Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, touchpad

On my Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100, the keyboard is not working. No matter what I press nothing responds. The touch screen is still working, and everything seems to be working properly, but I have zero keyboard function! When I went into the device manager and looked at the error message it say that windows can't start this hardware because its configuration in the registry is incomplete or damaged. I've tried all of the trouble shooting basics and I'm in the registry now I just don't know what to do. Any suggestions? I was up a few nights ago using my laptop and everything worked fine, the next morning when I woke up I opened it and turned it back on from sleep mode and none of my keys, nor mouse worked. Really strange to me, I did not add anything to my laptop or do anything, just simply used it one night woke up the next morning and can not use my key board for the last 3 days now.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/920851/keyboard-no-longer-works-on-toshiba-satellite-e45t-a4100 same question asked yday... with another user.

Answer (score -1):

Most a times there are no quick fixes for keyboard issues If you are not an I.T. professional, try reinstalling the operating system; go to the manufacturer's website, download the signed drivers and install them and see if this works. If problem persists, try replacing the keyboard. If replacing the keyboard doesn't remedy the problem, there must be an issue with the motherboard bus connecting the keyboard or maybe chip responsible for keyboard operations. Hope this helps.

Comment: Re-install the OS?! For a keyboard drivers issue?
This problem can be only caused by either hardware fault (which means that the OS is irrelevant) or a software **drivers** issue. In any case, no need to do such a radical move. Reinstalling the OS is quite the hassle